# Django join queries from multiple models

Tags: django

Consider following models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class MonthName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Month(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(MonthName)
    year = models.IntegerField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class EmployeeGroup(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Status(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class EmployeeStatus(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

I need to display some Employees with particular Status in specified Month. Along with their names i need to display group names they belong to. I could do something like this:

```
statuses = models.EmployeeStatus.objects.filter(month=some_month, status__name="Current")
groups = models.EmployeeGroup.objects.filter(month=some_month)
```

But to join these queries (assuming some sorting) i would have to iterate over them. Can i acheive this other way?

Looks like there should be model

```
class EmployeeData():
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

But redesigning application is the last resort - we have plenty of data already.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd be able to gather all this information by starting from the month model

```
statuses = some_month.employeestatus_set.filter(status__name='Current')
groups = some_month.employeegroup_set.all()
```

I'd imagine you'd then be able to use `select_related` as part of the query that retrieves `some_month` in the first place to fetch the status' and groups

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand this `select_related` part. Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: @MoonWolf - [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) (see also prefetch_related), used to stop django having to perform additional queries to fetch related models